# From AJAX action, returning JSON or HTML is preffered?

Tags: ajax, json

On my website landing page, I am calling various AJAX actions.But the performance is poor as of now.These actions are

1. To get latest articles
2. To get latest news
3. To get latest Jobs
4. To get recent added users etc.

I am showing all this information in dashboards for each AJAX actions.

My question is,

From my AJAX actions, should I return the HTML or JSON? Which one would be better in performance and maintainance point of view?

I have following few points on these approaches -

**HTML**

Pros-
1. Will be easy to code
2. Easy to maintain.If there is any UI change in dashboard, with HTML it would be easy to do.

Cons-
1. Performance hit as complete HTML would be sent on client side.

**JSON-**
Pros-
1. Good performance as data transfer size would be less.

Cons-
1. UI change in dashboard would be comparatively diffcult as I need to change JS code rendering logic.

I want to understand if my assumptions are correct or not.And if there are any other points in these approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading and embedding HTML directly as opposed to just sending the data and transferring it into a DOM structure client-side should not be so much different when it comes to performance.

Usually the greatest performance “killer” in an HTML page environment are HTTP requests – they take close to “forever” compared to all other stuff you do client-side. So if you have to pull data for multiple such widgets, it might be a good idea to encapsulate those data transfers into just *one* HTTP request, and have the different widgets read their data from there once its loaded. And for that, a data format like JSON might be preferable over HTML.